# How to copy different evenly spaced blocks of text from one file into multiple files containing each block

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

Let's say I have a text file like the following:

```
cheese
a b c 
d e f 
*

cheese
g h i 
j k l 
* 

cheese 
m n o 
p q r 
*
...
```

I wish to copy and append each block of text below the string `cheese` onto 3 other different files.

Meaning, let's say I have in files `1.txt`, `2.txt` and `3.txt` in some directory.

Once appended, `1.txt` should look like:

```
bla bla bla... 
a b c 
d e f 
*
```

and `3.txt` should look like:

```
bla bla bla...
m n o 
p q r 
*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/cheese/{
  close(file)
  outfile++
  file=outfile".txt"
  next
}
{
  print > (file)
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                   ##Starting awk program from here.
/cheese/{               ##Checking condition if line contains string cheese then do following.
  close(file)           ##Closing output file with close statement.
  outfile++             ##Increment variable outfile with 1 each time cursor comes here.
  file=outfile".txt"    ##Creating variable named file whose value is variable outfile and string .txt in it.
  next                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  print > (file)        ##Printing all lines into output file.
}
' Input_file            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```